# Nested asp:LinkButton within a Clickable List View row

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a list view that displays files and folders in a custom user control. The purpose of the user control is to allow users to select files and folders for various uses throughout the application. Each row that represents a folder has a toggle button to expand the folder and display all the contents, this folder is a `<asp:LinkButton>`. Each row has to be clickable as users can select the files and folders, therefore the item is an `<asp:LinkButton>` to trigger the `ItemCommand` event of the `<asp:ListView>`. I have attached a code sample below with the `CssClass` and irrelevant elements omitted.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" Id="ddtvContentItems" OnItemCommand="ddtvContentItems" OnItemDataBind="ddtvItemDataBind">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <Section>
         <asp:LinkButton Id="ContentArea" CommandName="Select" CommandArguement='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>
            <!-- Some more elements -->
            <div>
               <asp:LinkButton Id="btnExpandCollapse" CommandName="Toggle" CommandArguement='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
         </asp>LinkButton>
      </Section>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I understand the problems with using an `<asp:LinkButton>` (which renders as an `<a>`) inside another `<asp:LinkButton>`. I understand that anchor tags shouldn't be placed within anchor tags. The problem is I need an alternative to the containing `<asp:LinkButton>` and things like an `<asp:Panel>` (div) would not fire the `ItemCommand` event on click.

I have tried using panels and the `OnClick` on the client side and posting back. Although this works, this causes a post back and it re-renders.

```
function ContentSelect(id) {
__doPostBack("contentSelected:" + id); 
}
```

EDIT: trying what is in comments - adding an invisible button and using an asp:Panel as the container with an `onClick='$('btnSelect').Click();'`

Comment: Obvious solution: place your `toggle` button outside `select` area. Another solution is to use `aspTreeView` instead of `asp:ListView`.

Comment: Using asp tree view isn't an option

Comment: In any case, nested `a` (as well as `button`, `form`, etc) are not allowed.

Comment: Yes it's not valid HTML, so the sort of alternatives are user controls that trigger the item command event - I understand my problem

Comment: A trick can be like this: hide (separated) `linkButton`s and create `div` (or whatever) structure with `onclick="$('linkbtn').click();"`. 
Also make sure that `click` event bubbles to parent.